# SQL update only if different many columns

Tags: sql, sql-update

There is a discussion to update a field only if it is not equal

see [UPDATE if different](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6677517/update-if-different-changed)

I would like to implement similar to

```
UPDATE MyTable 
SET col1 = @newValue
WHERE Id = @Id AND col1 != @newValue
```

However question is how to do this if table has for example 20 columns:

Should I repeat Action above for each column (this would Limit update for those fields that really differ).

Or is better to do something like

```
 UPDATE xx 
 SET col1 = Value1, 
     col2 = Value2, 
     col3 = Value3...
 WHERE id = ID 
   AND (col1 != Value1 OR col2 != Value2 OR col3 != Value3)
```

This would update all 20 columns in one go even if only 1 column differs. Faster if for example 5 values need to be updated.

Comment: Apart from Gordon's answer, you might want to check out the implementation of `Slowly Changing Dimensions - Type 1` and ignore the `INSERT` part in it. The updates in SCD1 work the same way you want. And make sure to handle for `NULL` , as you can't compare `NULL` with `NULL` and it would give you an unexpected result.

Answer (score 3):

Your method is fine.  I would use `<>` rather than `!=`, because it is the traditional inequality operator in SQL.  You might want to check for `NULL` values -- but that doesn't seem to be an issue for this question.

In general, databases update *records* not *columns*.  That is, the entire record is read into memory, values are changed, and then the entire record is written back to storage.  This is an oversimplification -- there are locks and logging and dirty pages in the page cache -- but it captures the essence of what happens.

The overhead for `update` is generally on the writing and locking and logging side.  That has little to do with what fields are updated.

There are exceptions to this.  For instance, if you are using a columnstore database, then each column is stored separately.  In that case, a separate update for each column would be preferred.

Similarly, if some values are particularly large, they might be stored "off-page".  And that could affect update performance.

But, in general, your approach of ensuring that *some* column has changed is fine.